# Subdomain is not resolving to ipv6

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Please check below Bind DNS config for domain.com.
 Say ipv4 is 10.10.10.10 and ipv6 is FE80::903A:0:0:11E4. Cloudflare is used @CloudFlare A record is pointing to www.domain.com.
Subdomain data.domain.com is not allowed on CloudFlare.
Issue is subdomain data.domain.com is only resolving to ipv4, it is not resolving to ipv6.

```
; BIND data file for domain.com
;
$TTL 14400
@ IN SOA ns.domain.com. indo.domain.com. (
201006601 ; Serial
7200 ; Refresh
120 ; Retry
2419200 ; Expire
604800) ; Default TTL
;
domain.com. IN NS ns.domain.com.

domain.com. IN A 10.10.10.10
domain.com. IN AAAA FE80::903A:0:0:11E4
data IN A 10.10.10.10
data IN AAAA FE80::903A:0:0:11E4

ns IN A 10.10.10.10

www IN CNAME domain.com.

=================================================
$TTL 14400
@ IN SOA ns.domain.com. indo.domain.com. (
201006601 ; Serial
7200 ; Refresh
120 ; Retry
2419200 ; Expire
604800) ; Default TTL
@                IN NS           ns.domain.com.
IN NS ns.domain.com.

ns    IN      A       10.10.10.10


4 IN PTR domain.com.

200       IN  PTR       ns.domain.com.

201       IN  PTR       data.domain.com.

FE80::903A:0:0:11E4          IN      PTR     data.domain.com.
```

---

```
root@zone:~# dig data.domain.com -tAAAA 
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> data.domain.com -tAAAA 
;; global options: +cmd 
;; Got answer: 
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30049 
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0 

;; QUESTION SECTION: 
;data.domain.com. IN AAAA 

;; AUTHORITY SECTION: 
domain.com. 1051 IN SOA may.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2013083012 10000 2400 604800 3600 
;; Query time: 2 msec 
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) 
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 31 18:24:15 2013 
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 90
```

Comment: Can you add the output for `dig data.domain.com -tAAAA`?

Comment: `root@zone:~# dig data.domain.com -tAAAA
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> data.domain.com -tAAAA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30049
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;data.domain.com.                   IN      AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
domain.com.                1051    IN      SOA     may.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2013083012 10000 2400 604800 3600

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 31 18:24:15 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90`

Comment: What does *Subdomain data.domain.com is not allowed on CloudFlare.* mean?  You seem to be trying to run your own Bind server to serve up just that subdomain while CloudFlare is authoritative for your domain.  This *can* work, but you will have to delegate that subdomain to your nameserver in CloudFlare and I don't know if they support that.  Do you just want to add your own IPv6 address for a subdomain in CloudFlare?

Comment: It's my requirement not to allow content on subdomain to get through CloudFlare's network.

Comment: So why are you setting up a whole DNS server? You could just put the IPv6 address into CloudFlare's control panel and have done with it.

Comment: www.domain.com should accessed with only CloudFlare and it's subdomain data.domain.com should accessed from original server itself where both www.domain.com and data.domain.com are hosted.

Comment: So? You just put the AAAA record in CloudFlare and make sure that it's set to bypass CloudFlare.

Comment: Yes, I have done this change, added AAAA record to bypass from CloudFlare's network, hopefully, it will work, will take sometime in DNS changes on internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addresses beginning with the FE80::/10 prefix are link-local addresses and are not for use on the public internet. You would need something in the 2000::/3 range, which is in the global unicast address range. Basically, if you have an FE80::/10 address, the only devices that could contact that server would be devices on the same subnet.

For more information, see:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments.xhtml

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

---

The above is just the tip of the iceberg with your issue though. As pointed out in the comments, you seem to have a lack of knowledge about how DNS works. I'd consider reading up on DNS, delegation, and authoritative name servers, *then* get a publicly accessible IPv6 address and solve your issue accordingly.

Comment: It's client's server, client is not allowing me to show their real domain name and public IPs, hence I have used private IPs instead of real public IPs.

Comment: Well we're not mind readers...

Comment: @Hrishi See [RFC 3849](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3849).

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't clear this initially.